# Systray stretching out for no reason

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, notification-area

I just restored my Windows install back to a previous state with Macrium. For some odd reason it is now stretching out my systray up to halfway across my taskbar. Any ideas why? No it did not do this 6 months ago when I took the image or anytime after that when I was using it. This is in Windows 7x64. The blank area seems to be filled with blank icons because if I place the mouse anywhere in the blank area the systray will slide over by about 1 icon's width. The missing icon between the battery and the volume is I assume my network icon. Not sure why that is missing as well.

[image]

Comment: Seems to me like when you did a System Restore, it did something to the registry for the systray. What happens when you reboot?

Comment: Standard rebooting does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to attempt to rebuild your icon cache, it may be the source of your problem.

Type in the following commands EXACTLY as displayed in an elevated command prompt (type in cmd in the start menu, then right click on cmd.exe when it shows up and select "Run as administrator"

```
     taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F

     CD /d %userprofile%\AppData\Local

     DEL IconCache.db /a 

     shutdown /r
```

This should solve your problem as soon as the system reboots.